# Persisting query string with AngularJS routing

Tags: angularjs

I've been working on a large Angular app for almost a year now and I'm stuck trying to do what I expected to be trivial.

Here are two routes I have with params (shortened for brevity):

```
/a/:id
/a/:id/b
```

Let's say the user is at `/a/1` and the query string is modified, for example:

```
/#/a/1?foo=123&bar=456
```

I want to have a link on the page that directs the user to the second route `/a/1/b` while maintaining the query string, so the end result is a redirection to:

```
/#/a/1/b?foo=123&bar=456
```

I am using Angular 1.2 and the new ngRoute module.

**What is the best way to achieve this behavior?**

---

**Edit:**
I should mention I have a working solution right now that seems terrible to me.  The link is bound to an `ng-click` handler which is essentially the following:

```
$scope.navigateToBClick = function() {
  var path = $location.path() + '/b',
    search = $location.search();
  $location.url(path + '?' + $.param(search));
};
```

Comment: have you figured out another solution yet? This does seems terrible to me.

Comment: you could just call $location.path($location.path()+ '/b'); instead of what you are doing. The search string will be appended when changing routes using path. Explain what you find terrible please.

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem. My query string always persists, and I don't want it to do so. I'm using the default `$locationProvider.html5Mode = false`. I imagine if we resolve one problem, the other will be trivial. Also, my links are in `<a>` tags. I'm wondering if this is part of the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you would consider this a better solution than what you've got, but it is a solution.

In your initialization code, add the following:

```
app.run(["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (e, current) {
        $rootScope.query = $.param(current.params);
    });
}]);
```

Then, in your HTML, make your links as follows:

```
<a ng-href="#/a/{{id}}/b?{{query}}">Navigate to B</a>
```

Comment: Consider using `ng-href` instead of `href` when you have {{}} in your url. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly the question then we can solve it with **$locationChangeStart** $rootScope event. This is done in run phase. 
Basic idea is : on every location change we will check if we had query string in url (searching for '?' in the url, if there is query string , then we add it to the new url.

```
    angular.module('your_module').run(function ($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {

      // If we have queryString on currentURL , then we will add it to the next url
        if(oldUrl.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
         // this can be optimized if we want to check first for queryString in the new url,
         // then append only new params, but that's additional feature.
        newUrl += '?' + oldUrl.split('?')[1];
      }
   });
```

In HTML we just call **$location.path('a/1/b')** , url params (query strings) will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if route is /#/a/1?foo=123&bar=456  then redirect to /#/a/1/b?foo=123&bar=456

I have worked on /#a?foo=bar to /#b?foo=bar, it can be easily tweaked to /#a/b?foo=bar and  used angular-route-segment library.

Run the plunker at http://run.plnkr.co/HvSyw4aMUiy1mwC3/#/firstRoute?foo=bar

and see the code here

http://plnkr.co/edit/ylFM8BHRXpqpMV7QVEcJ

Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I've found so far is to trace all `$location.search()` changes and store `$window.location.search` in a scope variable after each search change.

Then just add this scope variable to all anchors in a template:

```
<a ng-href="/projects/{{ projectId }}{{ queryString }}">
    Title
</a>
```

In this case both routes reads scope variables from routeParams query string and uses `$scope.$watch` on those variables to reflect changes in `$location.search` and thus in anchors `href` attributes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

//Controller

```
$scope.menu = {path:"admin", name: "Administration"};
var queryString = $location.$$url.split("?")[1];
if (queryString) {
    $scope.queryString = "?" + queryString;
}
```

//View

```
<a ng-href="#/{{menu.path}}{{queryString}}">{{menu.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used that caused persistent query string propagation (that I didn't want).

```
el.find('li').has('ul').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    // handle clicks manually
    e.stopPropagation();
    // if the anchor tag has a specific class
    if (el.hasClass('link')) {
        var path = el.attr('href').replace('#', '');
        scope.$apply(function () {
            // changing the path changes only the path
            // the query string is left intact
            $location.path(path);
        });
    }
});
```