# angular set route with query using anchor href

Tags: angularjs

In angular.js, how can I set the route using an anchor tag's href, but containing a query parameter too? I'm using html5Mode and it seems that the following:

```
 <a href="/my/profile?scrollTo=someElementId"></a>
```

ends up escaping the question mark before it sets the url.

I need to set the url exactly as is. How can I prevent it from escaping the question mark?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21734167/1632286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are using the default Angular router, the documentation says it all. Take a look at their example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).
2. If you are looking for a more robust router, I suggest you switch to [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

[Here's how](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) you deal with query params, although you might just use URL parameters instead for pretty URLs.

With ui-router you don't have to use 
`href`, you can pass query params to a route using ui-sref. Check out [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2JhV4PcYpKJdBCwHIWS?p=preview) to see how.